# About to upgrade, what are EE differences between 2.81 and 2.92?

Tags: forms, upgrade, ee2-upgrades

About to upgrade my personal site and went to Ellislab website for download and they have 2 versions for download. 2.81 and 2.92

Going through the EE bug tracker appears I may have several items that I will need to edit core files if I end up with these all ready listed bugs.

Is there a reason some of us would not want to upgrade to 2.92 now? with Forums 3.1.17?

I'm currently running 2.81.

Thanks
`mike

Comment: Actually EllisLab started providing access to older version as of Dec 2014 - check this blog post https://ellislab.com/blog/entry/downloading-previous-versions

Answer (score 1):

In cases like this, you should check out [the Change Log](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/about/changelog.html).

There are a couple of changes that stand out:

- EE2.9 requires at least PHP 5.3.10 (EE2.8 requires 5.2);
- In EE2.9, the [conditionals parser](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/conditionals.html) has had an overhaul. This means your templates can be more performant, but conditionals are also more error-prone.

As so often, it's a case of YMMV.

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned i also looked through the change logs as always, but this is the 1st time I have seen EE offer 2 versions for download. Guess i'm more worried about what might break add-ons

Comment: I think that, by now, most add-ons will be 2.9 compatible. If you're unsure, ask the developers.

Comment: The security updates in 2.9.x vs 2.8.x are significant as well. Unrelated, but something to consider since you're thinking about updating: on the PHP requirements, if you need to request an upgrade from your host, go ahead and ask for PHP 5.5–there are many free performance gains.